# Angular Material Table automatic scroll

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-5

Is there any way to scroll the Angular Material Table in the code behind?

I have a requirement that the table should be always at the bottom bosition when the page loads. Unfortunately paging is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, scrollable elements in angular material with scroll capability use [cdkScrollable directive](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview), but it doesn't seem to be the case with `mat-table`

So for now you could bypass it by directly accessing the element, and scroll to a high y value

```
  scrollBottom() {
    document.querySelector('mat-table').scrollBy(0, 10000);
  }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vu7msb)

Comment: Now I see that the `mat-table` doesn't have scrollbars at all, maybe that's why it doesn't have the directive.The scrollbars were in a the div container of the `mat-table`. I applied the `.scrollBy()` method to the `div` and it worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: There is scrolling in there if table height is fixed. But you prevent that with its  pagination feature.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the accepted answer, you need to scroll the table once the data has been loaded. In my case I provide various data filter options for the user and the scrolling to the bottom needs to happen when any of those are changed too. This can be achieved using a `ContentObserver` from the CDK Observers module.

You need to wrap the table in an element:

```
<div id="tableWrapper">
    <mat-table>
        ...
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

Then, in the component class:

```
...
import {ContentObserver} from '@angular/cdk/observers';
...

export class MyComponent {

    constructor(private readonly contentObserver: ContentObserver) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.contentObserver.observe(document.querySelector('#tableWrapper'))
        .subscribe(this.tableContentChanged);
      // Load the table data here
    }

    tableContentChanged() {
      const table = document.querySelector('mat-table');
      table.scrollBy(0, table.scrollHeight);
    }
}
```